# Difference between ni Yotte and ni Taishite

Tags: grammar, word-choice

From http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B-ni-yotte-ni-yoru/:
人によって考え方が違う。
Everyone has a different point of view.
hito ni yotte kangaekata ga chigau.

Can I use 人に対して考え方が違う(hito ni taishite kangaekata ga chigau).
Using the "in regards to" meaning of に対して(ni taishite).

Also I'm confused as to why these 2 have to be used.
In many cases I feel that the 対して(taishite)/よって(yotte) can just be changed to 'には(ni wa)' and convey the same meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**によって** and **に対して** are not interchangeable. They are also not replaceable with **には**.

人**によって**考え方が違う。Depending on the person, thoughts differ.

人**に対して**考え方が違う。Thoughts regarding people differ.

（何か）**に対して**、人**によって**考え方が違う。 In regards to (some topic), depending on the person, thoughts differ.

人（人間）**に対して**人**によって**考え方が違う。Depending on the person, thoughts regarding people (humanity) differ.

海外の人**には**、人**によって**考え方が違う。Among foreigners, depending on the person, thoughts differ.

---

**によって** is specifying a separate relationship with each member of the subject group and the predicate.

**に対して** is presenting its object in opposition to the subject.

For example:

報告書**によって**、結果が違う。Depending on the report, the results differ.

報告書**に対して**、結果が違う。Regarding the report, the results differ (from something else, not necessarily other reports).

**には** is a method of refining the subject of discussion. The nuance, and grammatical use, is quite different from the other two. That doesn't seem to be your main question, though, so I'll leave it at that regarding **には**.

Comment: Some of your sentences make little to no sense, I am afraid.   Those are  「人（人間）に対して人によって考え方が違う。」、「海外の人には、人によって考え方が違う。」 and 「報告書に対して、結果が違う。」.

Comment: Thank you for the help Coty! Putting them side by side really puts things into perspective.
l'électeur could you provide revisions to his wrong sentences then? For everyone's benefit.

Comment: @l'électeur 「人（人間）'hito' in the sense of 'ningen' に対して人 'hito' as individual people によって考え方が違う。」... 「海外の人には within the group of all foreigners、人によって考え方が違う。」... 「(あの)報告書に対して、(私たちの)結果が違う。」This last one is awkward, but it serves the purpose of answering the question, which is whether or not the two forms are identical.